Configuring the router to enable communication between two distinct IP addresses
I need assistance with establishing communication between two networks with different IP addresses.
In one of my projects, I have an embedded system with the IP address 172.20.10.129 and a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0. The customer's machine has an IP address of 10.3.3.180 and a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0. The customer needs to send MODBUS TCP/IP packets to my embedded system. However, due to the differences in IP addresses and subnet masks, we are currently unable to establish communication.
The customer is unable to change their IP address, and we also cannot modify our IP address to match theirs.
Could you please provide a solution to facilitate this communication?
Thank you.
We’re not sure how to proceed with this.

See, here the solution to this problem is very simple actually. If you have a straight connection between your's network "172.20.0.0/16" and "10.3.3.0/24" then in that case you can just configure static route in intermediate routers and the border routers of your end and the customer's end.
The reference topology is given below. If you have any other topology then it would be great if you could ping that here!


could you please provide more details on your solution? I didn't quite understand it, and unfortunately, we haven't been able to resolve the issue yet.
